# Is it possible to use MARY TTS engine on android application? Has anyone attempted this? Where would be a good place to start?

Tags: java, android, marytts

I'm interested in implementing the MARY TTS engine on Android, specifically
to use some of the advanced features available to the voices (such as
inflection, duration, pitch, etc). Ideally I would create a self-contained
Android application with a front-end (not MARY) to handle the text input
and generation, and a back-end (is MARY) to handle the Text-to-Speech task
and pass the audio files back to the front-end.

Has anyone attempted this? Where would be a good place to start?

Answer (score 1):

We have already start to solve this task with integrating MaryTTS java code to Android. Can tested from here

> https://github.com/AndroidMaryTTS